# lodash filter on key with multiple values

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

I am trying to find out in **`lodash`** `javascript library`, how to find out filter array of objects multiple values of key. *something similar to SQL - WHERE KEY in (val1, val2)*

Having said, with following example :

```
var users = [
   { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
   { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
   { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

_.filter(...)
```

**How can I find users, who's age in (34, 36) ??** 
*numbers can also change runtime*

Answer (score 8):

Lodash's [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#filter) accepts a predicate. You can create the predicate using partial application, so you can change the values easily:

```js
var users = [
   { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
   { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
   { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

var predicate = function(start, end) {
  return function(user) {
    return _.inRange(user.age, start, end + 1);
  }
}

var result = _.filter(users, predicate(34, 36));

console.log('inRange', result);

/** is equal predicate **/

var predicate = function() {
  var args = _.toArray(arguments);
  
  return function(user) {
    var equalToUserAge = _.partial(_.isEqual, user.age);
    
    return args.some(equalToUserAge);
  }
}

var result = _.filter(users, predicate(34, 40));

console.log('equals', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do this easily with vanilla JS as well (the example uses ES6):

```js
var users = [
   { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
   { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
   { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

const predicate1 = (start, end) => ({ age }) =>
  age >= start && age <= end;

const result1 = users.filter(predicate1(34, 36));

console.log('in range', result1);

const predicate2 = (...args) => ({ age }) =>
  args.some((num) => age === num);

const result2 = users.filter(predicate2(34, 40));

console.log('is equal', result2);
```

Comment: Actually, your suggestion works as **in between**, however I need exact matches, so it should return age ==34, or age ==36. what if I i need something (34, 40). your code returns 3 objects however I need to see only 2 objects for age 34 & 40.

Comment: Change the predicate to whatever you like. See example predicate in code.

Answer (score 4):

```
const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

const minAge = 34;
const maxAge = 36;

const filtered = _.filter(users, (user) => {
  return user.age >= minAge && user.age <= maxAge;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I had the same issue. I don't know if it is efficient but the below function returns what I am looking for. I had to flatten the result to keep the same format as the input.

```
var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
    { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
    { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

var ages = [{"age": 36},{"age": 34}]

function filterAges(array, vals) {
    var result=[];
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        result.push(_.filter( array, vals[i] ));
    }
    return _.flattenDepth(result, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 34, active: true}
];
var result = []
var x = _.filter(users, function(o) {
  _.map([36,34], function(p) {
    if (o.age == p) {
      result.push(o);
    }
  });
});
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -5):

You can do something like this:

```js
_.filter( object, { 'age': '34', 'age': '24' } );
```

The issue is if you are making this dynamically you can not have the same key in an object more than once.

Comment: Just as a note for why this will not work.  Because an object can have only one key, having 'age' set twice will mean that only the last one (24) will show up in the map.  This means you'll only filter for an age of 24 and not for the age of 34.