# Lodash filter with multiple options

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've checked [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922160/lodash-filter-on-key-with-multiple-values) on Stack Overflow, but they refer to ranges.

```
var users = [
   { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
   { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false },
   { 'user': 'Avding',   'age': 34, 'active': true }
];

_.filter(...)
```

I wish to filter based on multiple values, so with the above example I would like to do something like:

```
_.filter(users, { 'age': [36, 40], 'user': ['barney', 'Avding'] });
```

The expected result would just be Barney, as *Avding* is neither 36 or 40 years old.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare your own filter function.

```
_.filter(users, function (o) {
  return (o.age === 36 || o.age === 40) && (o.user === 'barney' || o.user === 'Avding');
});
```

Without the need to create a single comparison for each age or name:

```
var ages= [36, 40]
var users = ['barney', 'Avding']
_.filter(users, function (o) {
  return ages.includes(o.age) && users.includes(o.user);
});
```

Comment: Please see original question, I do not need to check ranges.

Comment: I edited the answer. The concept is that you can declare whatever comparison you need in your custom function

Comment: Would there be a better way to do the comparison,  seems a verbose way to check an array of ages that may be quite large.

Comment: @panthro `return [36, 40].includes(o.age) && ['barney', 'Avding'].includes(o.user)`

Comment: Edited again the answer to be more generic. But I mean, once you know you can use a function to define your own behaviour, it should be straightforward how to implement your desired behaviour

Comment: Great, answer, for extra credit, what if the user has a property that was an array, e.g. scores, `[10,20,30,40]`. and I needed to check if that user had a score that was either `[10,20]`?

Comment: @panthro [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: @Andreas do you have an example of some, can't seem to to get it to test an array with another array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520537/402037 - Just replace `.every()` with `.some()`

Answer (score 3):

Without using Lodash, you can use `filter` to loop through the array. Use `every` for a check of all check parameters. Use `includes` to check if an element is present in an array.

And use `Object.entries` to convert an object into an array.

```js
var users = [{"user": "barney", "age": 36, "active": true}, {"user": "fred", "age": 40, "active": false}, {"user": "Avding", "age": 34, "active": true}];
var search = Object.entries({'age': [36, 40], 'user': ['barney', 'Avding']});

var result = users.filter(o => search.every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k])));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to use lodash.

Comment: No problem. Just putting another option :)